# Android: Is publishing an application to Google Play with the default icon allowed?

Tags: android, publishing, google-play

Just want to know if publishing an application on Google play is allowed using the default Android icons ? My application got published successfully without and error, but it's been about four hours now and I still can't find it on Google play. So I am wondering whether using the default developer icon was a mistake. The documentation on icons don't mention anything about this matter either.

Your input on this matter is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is ok, some times it takes time to appear on google play, as it is being populated on all the server (*I guess*).

So keep patience, it will appear sooner, some times it may take 1 hour - 24 hours. :)

So while you are finger crossed, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9809682/593709)